# Prove that $\frac{a^{2}+1}{b}+\frac{b^{2}+1}{a} \geq 4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

$a$ and $b$ are both positive Real Numbers .

I saw this in a math olympiad, and within two days i couldn't solve it.

There is a simple case where:
$$\frac{a^{2}+1}{a}+\frac{b^{2}+1}{b} \geq 4 $$
We can solve it like this:
$$(a-1)^{2}\geq 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a^{2}-2a+1 \geq0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow a^{2}+1 \geq2a$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{a^{2}+1}{a} \geq2$$
With the same method:
$$\frac{b^{2}+1}{b} \geq2 $$
And when we add the two inequalities:
$$\frac{a^{2}+1}{a}+\frac{b^{2}+1}{b} \geq 4 $$
But in case where:
$$\frac{a^{2}+1}{b}+\frac{b^{2}+1}{a} \geq 4$$
I can’t solve it,
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Several solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1929487p13247167, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h378380p2090500

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with noticing that $a^{2} + 1 \geq 2\sqrt{a^{2}} = 2a$.

Similarly, we have that $b^{2} + 1 \geq 2b$.

Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^{2} + 1}{b} + \frac{b^{2} + 1}{a} \geq 2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right) \geq 4\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{b}{a}} = 4
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: How did you figure out the formula in the middle

Comment: It is a simple rearrangement. Indeed, we have that

$$\frac{a^{2}+1}{b} + \frac{b^{2}+1}{a} \geq \frac{2a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a} = 2\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right)$$

The proposed solution is the repeated application of the AM-GM inequality.

Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 3):

One can actually just use AM-GM directly:
$$\frac{a^2}b+\frac1b+\frac{b^2}a+\frac1a\geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^2}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{b}\cdot\frac{b^2}a\cdot\frac1a}=4\sqrt[4]{1}=4.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 1) Use AM-GM : $x^2+ 1\ge 2x$
2) UseAM-GM : $ t+\dfrac{1}{t} \ge 2$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $a,b$ are positive real numbers. Then we may assume $a\geq b$, hence $a^2+1\geq b^2+1$ and $\frac{1}{a}\leq\frac{1}{b}$, so the rearrangement inequality gives $$\frac{a^2+1}{b}+\frac{b^2+1}{a}\geq\frac{a^2+1}{a}+\frac{b^2+1}{b}\geq4$$ where the last inequality holds by what you already showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your method, making $(a-1)^2$ and $(b-1)^2$ appearing was a nice move.

$$\frac{a^2+1}{b}+\frac{b^2+1}{a}-4=\frac 1{\underbrace{ab}_{>0}}(\underbrace{a^3+a+b^3+b-4ab}_E)$$

Now use $2ab\le a^2+b^2$

$E\ge a^3+a+b^3+b-2a^2-2b^2=a(a-1)^2+b(b-1)^2\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

I would do this the following way--no knowledge of AM--GT needed: Assume WLOG $a \ge b$.
Then this inequality is clearly true for $a \ge 4$, as $\frac{a^2+1}{b} > a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a \ge b$. So now we are left to check the cases where both $a,b \le 3$; $a\ge b$. This can be done directly quite easily.